# How to render HTML Tags from ngModel?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I'm using AngularJS for binding JS variables to my HTML content, and it works fine.

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("Tabs", [])
  .controller("TabsController", ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.events = my_JS_object;
  })
```

**HTML**

```
<div>{{events.test}}</div>
```

It works as long as `my_JS_object.test` is a simple string, like `"Hello World"`, but once I try to put HTML tag in there, such as `Hello <b>World</b>` It doesn't use the tags as HTML elements, but as simple text. Which makes sense, only I have no idea how to make the HTML tags work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by Angular documentation, you can use inbuilt **ng-bind-html** directive to evaluate model string and insert resulting HTML into element.

Example: 
If you have model value like:

```
$scope.myHTML =
 'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
 '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
```

Use **ng-bind-html** like:

```
<p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
```

For detailed information go through: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

**Note:** Don't forget to inject **ngSanitize** service in your app.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `ngBindHtml` directive that properly evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the element in a secure way. To do this, you must include a reference to `angular-sanitize.js` in your HTML and then in your angular module, inject `ngSanitize`.

Like so

```
  var app = angular.module("Tabs", ['ngSanitize'])
     .controller("TabsController", ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.events = my_JS_object;
  })

 <div ng-controller="TabsController">
  <div ng-bind-html="events.test"></div>
 </div>
```

Here is a full working example:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myHTML = 'Hello This is <b>BOLD<b/>';
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="bindHtmlExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
     <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Refer to the official angular documentation for details:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert HTML into page you shouldn't do it this way. 
There is [sanitize](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.$sanitize) for this task.
For example in your controller:

```
$scope.trustedHtml = "<b>Hello World</b>"
```

And in your html:

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml "></div>
```

**Always check html if using a user given text before inserting.**

Also don't forget to add **ngSanitize** as dependency while creating controller

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to use transclusion if you want to embed custom HTML into your DOM tree.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.overwrite = false;
    $scope.origin = 'parent controller';
})
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.overwrite = !!scope.origin;
            scope.origin = 'link function';
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <my-directive>
            <p>HTML template</p>
            <p>Scope from {{origin}}</p>
            <p>Overwritten? {{overwrite}}</p>
        </my-directive>
    </div>
    
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-directive.html">
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
    <hr />
    <p>Directive template</p>
    <p>Scope from {{origin}}</p>
    <p>Overwritten? {{overwrite}}</p>
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Easier than using the `ng-bind-html` directive!?

Comment: For simplicity of writing code, ng-bind-html is way faster and easier to understand. It might be just my personal preference that I'd like to manage all the html blocks in my template than in my controllers.