# Angular - Cant update textarea after user input

Tags: angularjs, textarea, ng-options, ng-bind

Im having an issue with Anuglar. `ng-bind` doesnt update textarea once its value has been altered by user input.

Note: The reason im using ng-bind instead of ng-model is that I need `ng-bind-html` as the input is in html sanatized using `ngSanitize`.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11682/

Here is how to see what im talking about: Select anyvalue from dropdown and textarea is updated. But select `New Value` and put some text in the textarea. Then change the select box to any value and textarea never changes again!

Code:

[SCRIPT]

```
$scope.msg_templates = []; //array of {id, title, msg} filled with required stuff
$scope.msg_templates[0] = {id:'0', title:'{New Value}', msg:''}; //first item is to enter new value
$scope.msg_templates[1] = {id:'1', title:'TTT', msg:'TTT'};
$scope.msg_templates[2] = {id:'2', title:'XXX', msg:'XXX'};
.
.

//set default value
$scope.msg_sel = '';
$scope.msg_field = '';

//change msg function
$scope.change_msg_sel = function()
{
    if($scope.msg_sel==null){
    $scope.msg_field = '';
    return false;
    }

    $scope.msg_field = $scope.msg_sel.msg;
};
```

[HTML]

```
<select ng-model="msg_sel" ng-change="change_msg_sel()" ng-options="v.title for v in msg_templates">
<option value="">Please Select -</option>
</select>

<textarea ng-bind-html="msg_field"></textarea>
```

Comment: is `v.title for v in msg_templates` intentional or is it suppose to be using `comm_templates`? And you should be using `<textarea ng-model="msg_field"` instead of `<textarea ng-bind="msg_field"`

Comment: its actually `msg_templates`, forgot to rename it here for this example.

Comment: Works fine for me [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0yoxpd11/1/). Only difference in my fiddle is I removed the wrapping `ngApp` from `<body ng-app="myApp">` because you can't have an `ng-app' within another. You are aware that `$scope.msg_templates[0]` has blank `msg` so when selected nothing will show.

Comment: yea I know its empty, thats what its suppose to be.

Comment: and no your version doesnt work. Select "TTT", and alter the value, and then change selectbox.

Comment: ok, I misunderstood. You should be using `ng-model` instead of `ng-bind` on the textarea

Comment: ok. but the reason I mentioned `ng-bind` is that I had to use `ng-bind-html` as the input is html and sanatised using ngSanitize. (like explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148579/how-to-render-html-tags-from-ngmodel)

Answer (score 2):

Solve the problem myself, just manually override the field's value inside `$scope.change_msg_sel` using the **good-ol-always-working-vintage-JS**!

`document.getElementById('msg_field').value=$scope.msg_field;`

(so much for the `amazing angular`!!)

Comment: Hi sir I am facing similar issue, I am new to angularjs so I can't able to understand how to solve it in my case, I am having one text-area where user can select pre written text from dropdown but once user write any manual text, angularjs stops updating the value. Can you please help me with this.
here is the link to my question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/69612912/16632970